# Scala: Generic implicit converters?

Tags: scala, implicit, typeclass

I would like to define a generic implicit converter that works for all subtypes of type `T`. For example:

```
abstract class Price[A] {
  def price(a: Any): Int
}

trait Car
case class Prius(year: Int) extends Car
trait Food
case class FriedChicken() extends Food

object Def {
  implicit def carToPrice[A <: Car](car: A): Price[A] = new Price[A] {
    def price(car: Any) = 100
  }

  implicit def foodToPrice[A <: Food](food: A): Price[A] = new Price[A] {
    def price(food: Any) = 5
  }

  // implicit object PriusPrices extends Price[Prius] {
  //   def price(car: Any) = 100
  // }
  // 
  // implicit object FriedChickenPrices extends Price[FriedChicken] {
  //   def price(food: Any) = 5
  // }
}

import Def._  

def add [A, B >: A](stuff: A, list: List[(B, Price[_])])(implicit p: Price[A]) = (stuff, p) :: list
val stuff = add(Prius(2000), add(FriedChicken(), Nil))
stuff map { x => x._2.price(x._1) }
```

The above code throws an error:

```
error: could not find implicit value for parameter p: Price[FriedChicken]
       val stuff = add(Prius(2000), add(FriedChicken(), Nil))
                                       ^
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Update**:

As [@extempore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843543/scala-generic-implicit-converters/3844366#3844366) pointed out, what's wrong is that I am confusing implicit conversions (view bounds) and context bounds (both make use of implicit parameters). There's nothing wrong with my generic implicit converters. The problem is that `add` is using context bounds instead of a view. So we can fix it as follows:

```
def add [A, B >: A](stuff: A, list: List[(B, Price[_])])(implicit view: A => Price[A]) = (stuff, view(stuff)) :: list
```

An interesting thing @extempore demonstrates in his code is that we don't really need a generic converter if `Price[A]` was contravariant. Basically, I can make `Price[Car]` work on behalf of `Price[Prius]`, which is kind of what I wanted. So the alternative context bound version is:

```
abstract class Price[-A] {
  def price(a: Any): Int
}

implicit object CarPrice extends Price[Car] {
  def price(a: Any) = 100
}

implicit object FoodPrice extends Price[Food] {
  def price(a: Any) = 1
}
```

**Related**:

- [[scala] Generic implicit converters?](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/7599)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not very clear what you really want.  You are indeed mixing up implicit conversions and implicit parameters.  Rather than try to sort it out I wrote some code.

```
object Test {
  type Price = Int
  abstract class Pricable[-A] {
    def price(a: A): Price
  }

  trait Car
  case class Prius(year: Int) extends Car
  trait Food
  case class FriedChicken() extends Food

  implicit val CarPricingGun = new Pricable[Car] { 
    def price(a: Car): Price = 100
  }
  implicit val FoodPricingGun = new Pricable[Food] { 
    def price(a: Food): Price = 1
  }
  implicit def priceableItemToPrice[A: Pricable](x: A) =
    implicitly[Pricable[A]] price x

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val x1 = Prius(2000)
    val x2 = FriedChicken()

    println("Price of " + x1 + " is " + (x1: Price))
    println("Price of " + x2 + " is " + (x2: Price))
  }
}
// Output is:
//
// Price of Prius(2000) is 100
// Price of FriedChicken() is 1
//
```

Comment: I want to 1) deal with implicit conversion for a family of type in one shot 2) store various objects supporting the typeclass in some container and use it later. I did not think of using contravariance, but it totally makes sense so `Price[Car]` can act as `Price[Prius]`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you've defined your implicit `carToPrice` and `foodToPrice` as implicit *methods* from a `Car` and `Food` values to `Price`s, yet no `Car` and `Food` values are in evidence where you need the conversions. Since you don't actually use the arguments in these implicit methods, what I think you really want is implicit *values*, like so:

```
implicit def carToPrice[A <: Car]/*(car: A)*/: Price[A] = new Price[A] {
  def price(car: Any) = 100
}

implicit def foodToPrice[A <: Food]/*(food: A)*/: Price[A] = new Price[A] {
  def price(food: Any) = 5
}
```

Comment: Including food into conversion doesn't seem to solve it though:implicit def foodToPrice[A <: Food](food: A): Price[A] = new Price[A] {
    def price(a: Any) = food match {
      case chicken: FriedChicken => 2
      case _ => 1
    } 
  }

Comment: My suggestion is that you *don't* depend on a food argument (I commented it out in my answer).

Comment: If you want to pattern match, do it on the argument to `price`.

Comment: I see that your version works, but it's just not clear to me why mine is any different from `implicit def intToString(x: Int) = x.toString`.

Comment: I added what I think is going on at the end of the question.

Answer (score 0):

As [@extempore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843543/scala-generic-implicit-converters/3844366#3844366) pointed out, what's wrong is that I am confusing implicit conversions (view bounds) and context bounds (both make use of implicit parameters). There's nothing wrong with my generic implicit converters. The problem is that `add` is using context bounds instead of a view. So we can fix it as follows:

```
def add [A, B >: A](stuff: A, list: List[(B, Price[_])])(implicit view: A => Price[A]) = (stuff, view(stuff)) :: list
```